# Problem with running SL 4 application as standalone

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I ahve silverlight 4 application and when I run it as standalone I see error in chrome console

```
Uncaught Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2152    
Category: InitializeError       
Message: Failed to download a platform extension: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.zip
```

When I run it hosted in asp.net application it runs and everything is ok with that application

I need to run it as standalone to test it by ant profiler

How can I run it in demanded mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to turn off the "Reduce XAP size by using application library caching" option in order to run the app as standalone.

I'm curious as to why running it from a web application changes things for the ant profiler?  I can't see how that makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you once again :) there is just no radiobutton to test in as hosted application :)